# How to create a function to pass these cards from hand to another

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a way to pass five playing cards thru five players hands. I have created a way to do so in the `main()` but was looking for an idea to create a function that takes the card and passes to another hand so I am not repeating my line of code so much in the `main()`. Just needed some ideas.

```
import time

class Card(object):
    """ A playing card. """
    RANKS = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
             "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]
    SUITS = ["c", "d", "h", "s"]

    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.rank = rank 
        self.suit = suit

    def __str__(self):
        rep = self.rank + self.suit
        return rep



class Hand(object):
    """ A hand of playing cards. """
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []

    def __str__(self):
        if self.cards:
           rep = ""
           for card in self.cards:
               rep += str(card) + "  "
        else:
            rep = "<empty>"
        return rep


    def clear(self):
        self.cards = []

    def add(self, card):
        self.cards.append(card)

    def give(self, card, other_hand):
        self.cards.remove(card)
        other_hand.add(card)



def passAgain(passAgain):
    if passAgain == "y" or passAgain == "yes":
        card1 = Card("A", "s")
        card2 = Card("2", "s")
        card3 = Card("3", "s")
        card4 = Card("4", "s")
        card5 = Card("5", "s")


        firstHand = Hand()
        secondHand = Hand()
        thirdHand = Hand()
        fourthHand = Hand()
        lastHand = Hand()


        firstHand.add(card1)
        firstHand.add(card2)
        firstHand.add(card3)
        firstHand.add(card4)
        firstHand.add(card5)

        print ("First hand contains:",firstHand,)

        firstHand.give(card1, secondHand)
        print ("First hand gives first card to second hand and now has:", firstHand,)
        print ("Second hand now has:", secondHand,)

        firstHand.give(card2, secondHand)
        print ("First hand gives second card to second hand and now has:", firstHand,)
        print ("Second hand now has:", secondHand,)

        firstHand.give(card3, secondHand)
        print ("First hand gives third card to second hand and now has:", firstHand,)
        print ("Second hand now has:", secondHand,)

        firstHand.give(card4, secondHand)
        print ("First hand gives fourth card to second hand and now has:", firstHand,)
        print ("Second hand now has:", secondHand,)

        firstHand.give(card5, secondHand)
        print ("First hand gives last card to second hand and now has:", firstHand,)
        print ("Second hand now has:", secondHand,)
        print("\n")
        time.sleep(2)




        secondHand.give(card1, thirdHand)
        print ("Second hand gives first card to third hand and now has:", secondHand,)
        print ("Third hand now has:", thirdHand,)

        secondHand.give(card2, thirdHand)
        print ("Second hand gives second card to third hand and now has:", secondHand,)
        print ("Third hand now has:", thirdHand,)


        secondHand.give(card3, thirdHand)
        print ("Second hand gives third card to third hand and now has:", secondHand,)
        print ("Third hand now has:", thirdHand,)

        secondHand.give(card4, thirdHand)
        print ("Second hand gives fourth card to third hand and now has:", secondHand,)
        print ("Third hand now has:", thirdHand,)

        secondHand.give(card5, thirdHand)
        print ("Second hand gives last card to third hand and now has:", secondHand,)
        print ("Third hand now has:", thirdHand,)
        print("\n")
        time.sleep(2)



        thirdHand.give(card1, fourthHand)
        print ("Third hand gives first card to fourth hand and now has:", thirdHand,)
        print ("Fourth hand now has:", fourthHand,)

        thirdHand.give(card2, fourthHand)
        print ("Third hand gives second card to fourth hand and now has:", thirdHand,)
        print ("Fourth hand now has:", fourthHand,)

        thirdHand.give(card3, fourthHand)
        print ("Third hand gives third card to fourth hand and now has:", thirdHand,)
        print ("Fourth hand now has:", fourthHand,)

        thirdHand.give(card4, fourthHand)
        print ("Third hand gives fourth card to fourth hand and now has:", thirdHand,)
        print ("Fourth hand now has:", fourthHand,)

        thirdHand.give(card5, fourthHand)
        print ("Third hand gives last card to fourth hand and now has:", thirdHand,)
        print ("Fourth hand now has:", fourthHand,)
        print("\n")
        time.sleep(2)


        fourthHand.give(card1, lastHand)
        print ("Fourth hand gives first card to last hand and now has:", fourthHand,)
        print ("Last hand now has:", lastHand,)

        fourthHand.give(card2, lastHand)
        print ("Fourth hand gives second card to last hand and now has:", fourthHand,)
        print ("Last hand now has:", lastHand,)

        fourthHand.give(card3, lastHand)
        print ("Fourth hand gives third card to last hand and now has:", fourthHand,)
        print ("Last hand now has:", lastHand,)

        fourthHand.give(card4, lastHand)
        print ("Fourth hand gives fourth card to last hand and now has:", fourthHand,)
        print ("Last hand now has:", lastHand,)

        fourthHand.give(card5, lastHand)
        print ("Fourth hand gives last card to last hand and now has:", fourthHand,)
        print ("Last hand now has:", lastHand,)
        print("\n")




def main():
    while True :
        print ("Do you want to pass cards? Press y or yes")
        print("\n")

        ans = input ()
        passAgain(ans)


main()
```

Comment: Maybe i can append the (card, Hand) somehow?

Comment: To me it's not so clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to implement a way that the receiving hand is able to pass the card it was given directly to another player, i.e., without adding it first?

Comment: I am basically just moving five cards through five players hands- the fifth player will have all five cards in the end and the other four players will have zero, teacher mentioned a swap function possibly?

Comment: so basically it will shorten up all the crap i have in the main() somehow

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with this:

```
def passAgain():
    # This line create all empty Hand objects.
    table_hands = [Hand() for _ in range(5)]

    # These 3 lines creates the 5 cards involved
    for value in ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5"]:
        for suite in ["s"]:
            table_hands[0].add(Card(value, suite))

    # Cycle the hands  
    for i, hand in enumerate(table_hands):
        # Create pairs of hands, one giving and another receiving.
        hands_passing = table_hands[i:i + 2]

        if len(hands_passing) == 2:
            # If we have two hands involved, create a list of cards that 
            #  will be given.
            giving_hand = hands_passing[0].cards[:]
            for card in giving_hand:
                hands_passing[0].give(card, hands_passing[1])
                print(table_hands)

def main():
    while True :
        ans = input("Do you want to pass cards? Press y or yes: ")
        if ans in ("y", "yes"):
            passAgain()
        else:
            break
```

Comment: this looks pretty good thank you!, is there also a way to use a swap function? i am not really familiar with it though but my teacher mentioned possibly using it.

Comment: Stackoverflow discourages homework questions. If this answer fits your question you should accept it. If you have more questions, you should submit them as new ones. I'll give you a hint: a swapping function should take two hands as arguments and swap all their cards at once.